# LeanFT 14,5 file upload functionality

Tags: leanft

Can you please let me know why my file upload functionality is NOT working:

```
@Test
public void testUploadFile() throws GeneralLeanFtException {        
    //Launch Chrome
    Browser browser = BrowserFactory.launch(BrowserType.CHROME);        
    browser.navigate("https://uploadfiles.io/");        
    //This is NOT getting invoked while running
    browser.describe(WebElement.class, new WebElementDescription.Builder()
           .innerText("Drop file here or click to upload. (5GB max) ").tagName("FORM").build()).click();                
}
```

What can I do?

Comment: is it recognized? (highlight and other basic methods work)?

Comment: How you do you know it doesn't get invoked? What errors do you see?